# What file permissions should I set before I give website project folder to hosting service?

Tags: web-hosting, security, permissions, jekyll

I am using a CMS called [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) to build a website. My understanding of jekyll at this point is that it helps me to generate static web pages by providing me a simple boilerplate for a website and allowing me to use sass.

Due to permissions issues with [Atom.io](https://atom.io/) not allowing me to save my files, I have set most of my files to 777. Jekyll is very convenient by taking my files and generating a _site folder which contains the actual generated html documents and css. Most of these files within the _site folder seem to have the same permissions of 777. I did not set the permissions of this specific folder manually so I do not know if this my unintentional doing or if it is the way it is supposed to be.

I will very soon be handing this _site folder over to a hosting service in order for them to make the website live. My question is what file permissions should I set for the files in this folder before I submit it to the hosting service in order to avoid problems with security, access, other things?

Comment: If these are simple HTML files, all you need to do is make sure that the user that Apache user can read it. Often that is just a matter of changing owner and group to the Apache user and the file permissions so that at least the owner can read it. You may need to set group read permissions too, but I doubt it.

Comment: I am not aware of file permissions requirements of Jekyll. While you host your website at web server, following are the ideal permissions,

public_html == 750
sub-folders within public_html == 755
all files == 644

Answer (score 1):

> My question is what file permissions should I set for the files in
>   this folder before I submit it to the hosting service in order to
>   avoid problems with security, access, other things?

There are many different types of hosting services, e.g.: your files won't have the same permissions on a shared hosting than in a dedicated server.

It doesn't matter what are the permissions on your local filesystem, you have to make sure that your files will be secure in your web hosting, so it doesn't matter what are the permission of the files that `Jekyll` generates in the `_site` directory on your own filesystem, you have to read your hosting service documentation to make sure that they are safe in this new environment.